# Empty GeoDataFrame when using .merge GeoPandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, geopandas

I'm trying to merge a pandas dataframe and a geopandas geodataframe by using an attribute joins. I'm using a US counties shape file (https://geonet.esri.com/thread/24614 first response) and a csv file (http://water.usgs.gov/watuse/data/2010/index.html the first Excel format then saved as a csv). Once the dataframes are joined by using FIPS I try to print the new geodataframe, but only the headers print with the message Empty GeoDataFrame above. Here's the code I'm using

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import csv 
import numpy as np
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import csv
from shapefile import Reader 

df1 = pd.read_csv('usco2010.csv') 
#Reads csv file and puts it into a dataframe
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'STATE':df1['STATE'],'COUNTY':df1['COUNTY'],'FIPS':df1['FIPS'],'Se    rPop10^3':df1['TP-TotPop'],'WtrWthdrwl_MGD':df1['PS-WSWFr']})  
#Takes the data we want from df1 and creates a new dataframe df2: Statename, County name, FIPS, Served Population in 1000s, Surface water withdrawls in MGD 


counties = gpd.read_file('UScounties') 
#creates a GeoDataFrame for the US counties by using UScounties shapefile

print(counties.head())
print(df2.head())

counties = counties.merge(df2, on='FIPS') #Empty GeoDataFrame
#merges counties and df2 with same FIPS

print(counties)
```

Shouldn't the GeoDataFrame have the data from both objects being merged? I'd like to make a Choropleth Maps for fresh surface water withdraws.

Sorry if we're not suppose to list the data we use, I wanted to be as specific as possible. I'm new to python so I apologize if this is a simple question, but google and a search on this site do not show similar questions that have been answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just checked your problem. From what I see, the problem was that the columns you were trying to merge on where of two different data types. Your column in the counties dataset was of a type object (e.g. it contained strings) while the df2["FIPS"] was of type "int64". This is what I did, and the merge work. Still give it a check to see if the merged was appropriately carried out:

```
us_data = pd.read_csv('usco2010.csv') 
counties = gp.read_file('UScounties.shp') 
counties["FIPS"] = counties["FIPS"].astype(int)
pd.merge(counties, us_data, on="FIPS")
```

Comment: Yes that is the solution, thank you. On a first glance through everything looks like it was merged correctly. Thank you so much for your quick reply.